# How to fix thread starvation in Azure App Service?

Tags: multithreading, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an App Service on the [P1V2 pricing tier](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/) that I use as the backend for my mobile app. I don't usually have many users but a couple of months ago there was a peak of users that made the app service unusable hours at a time.

From the metrics, I can see that CPU and memory-wise the app service is fine but when the problem happens we do see the thread count going higher and higher. 
It seems every request eats up another thread but none of the threads are freed and so no requests are completed during the time. When that happens if we reset the app service the thread count goes down momentarily but then explodes again. 
The only mitigation I have right now is to scale out the service when this happens which takes a couple of minutes and will cost me a lot of money and effort.

I have played around with setting the minimum and maximum threads at the thread pool and also limiting the number of max concurrent requests per CPU but nothing has helped. I can reproduce the problem with just 5 of the most commonly used APIs. All of them make **asynchronous calls** to a SQL database also hosted on azure. I use ***async/await*** and context is disposed after the call. I use entity framework as our ORM.

The app service plan I pay for should have been able to handle the load easily and as long as there is no sudden peak of requests it does without a problem. But when the service goes down it can stay down for hours at a time and restarting or stopping the service doesn't help at all. We have reverted the backend to older versions and the problem still shows.

I can reproduce the problem easily by just blasting the backend with requests. Beneath you can find an example of what happens. One thing that points out at us is that no matter how many requests we send never have we seen the Http queue length go up.

[image]

Comment: clearly it's a problem in your code. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I agree with Thiago. problem appears to be with your code

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with just 5 of the most commonly used APIs. All of them make asynchronous calls to a SQL database also hosted on azure. I use async/await and context is disposed after the call. I use entity framework as ORM.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and a friend also reported to me the same exact weird behaviour. In this case the two projects are completelly unrelated. Scaling the App Service doesn't remove the issue completely. The machine with the high thread count is not removed from the load balancer so all the requests to that machine keep failing.

Comment: @WilsonVargas Were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

I'm facing the same exact problem and we don't have async/await access on DB.
The raise in thread usage is completely randomic.

Do you maybe use Redis cache and StackExchange? I'm putting my fiches on that (in my case).